# I am trying to use a nested IIF statement within an expression to return the date associated with a field where the field = Final

Tags: ms-access, expression

I have a table with multiple fields for contract dates and other fields that are populated with `Draft` or `Final` that correspond to the contract dates.

I am attempting to use a nested `iif` statement to populate a separate field that contains the date for the Final contract that will be used many other places within the DB that depend on that final date.

When I attempt to create the nested `iif` statement I receive an error message stating:

> The expression could not be saved because its result type, such as binary or NULL, is not supported by the server.

I have attempted to approach this several different ways, and this seems like it should be a basic `iif` statement but I am at a loss and don't know what to do.

The fields labeled `PS1 D/F` are short text and can contain `null`, `Draft`, or `Final`. the fields labeled `PS1 Completion Date_` contain a date formatted as Date/Time.

```
=IIf([PS1 D/F_1]="Final",[PS1 Completion Date_1],iif([PS1 D/F_2]="Final",[PS1 Completion Date_2],iif([PS1 D/F_3]="Final",[PS1 Completion Date_3],iif([PS1 D/F_4]="Final",[PS1 Completion Date_4],iif([PS1 D/F_5]="Final",[PS1 Completion Date_5],iif([PS1 D/F_6]="Final",[PS1 Completion Date_6],""))))))
```

This seems like a fairly simple expression and I would expect that if the `PS1 D/F_1` field contains `Final` that the date that is entered into the `PS1 Completion Date` field is populated, but instead I get error message:

> The expression could not be saved because its result type, such as binary or NULL, is not supported by the server.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message, I'm guessing that you're using a calculated field (which I would personally advise against, and would suggest performing all calculation using queries).

Nevertheless, I believe you receive the error because there is a chance that the expression could return multiple data types if the final 'else' argument is returned (which would return a string rather than a date).

As such, I might suggest that you modify the expression to the following:

```
=iif
(
    Nz([PS1 D/F_1],"")="Final",
    [PS1 Completion Date_1],
    iif
    (
        Nz([PS1 D/F_2],"")="Final",
        [PS1 Completion Date_2],
        iif
        (
            Nz([PS1 D/F_3],"")="Final",
            [PS1 Completion Date_3],
            iif
            (
                Nz([PS1 D/F_4],"")="Final",
                [PS1 Completion Date_4],
                iif
                (
                    Nz([PS1 D/F_5],"")="Final",
                    [PS1 Completion Date_5],
                    iif
                    (
                        Nz([PS1 D/F_6],"")="Final",
                        [PS1 Completion Date_6],
                        Null
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

You may also find it more readable to use a [`Switch`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) statement in lieu of successive nested `iif` statements, e.g.:

```
=switch
(
    Nz([PS1 D/F_1],"")="Final", [PS1 Completion Date_1],
    Nz([PS1 D/F_2],"")="Final", [PS1 Completion Date_2],
    Nz([PS1 D/F_3],"")="Final", [PS1 Completion Date_3],
    Nz([PS1 D/F_4],"")="Final", [PS1 Completion Date_4],
    Nz([PS1 D/F_5],"")="Final", [PS1 Completion Date_5],
    Nz([PS1 D/F_6],"")="Final", [PS1 Completion Date_6],
    True, Null
)
```

Comment: I am trying to add the formula as a calculated field. Typically I don't like to do this, but I am trying to cut down on the number of queries that I have to build and I thought that this would be simple. I've tried both of the above and neither will work. I am receiving an error message stating that the formulas cannot be used in a calculated column.